# My shield does not have further female headers? How do I stack more shields?

Tags: shields

I purchased a motor shield (L293D) and it doesn't have the female header which I can connect to another shield. What can I do to stack up more shields?
For being more specific I ordered my shield from here:
https://www.amazon.in/Simple-Labs-SLAEX039-Shield-Arduino/dp/B00K2Z3GAE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1518767182&sr=8-1&keywords=motor+shield+for+arduino+uno&dpID=41h0ag2SCgL&preST=_SX342_QL70_&dpSrc=srch

And please tell me how to do it because it is new for me. A guide or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many shields cannot be stacked, even if you replace the headers. The biggest reason is that the shield uses most of, if not all, the available pins. Motor shield often fall into this category, so they don't add the pointless expense of stackable headers.

Before you consider stacking any shields, whether they have stackable headers or not, you first need to learn how the shields work and what pins they require to ensure there are no conflicts.